How do I make multiple vertices and edges separated at the same distance inside object?
I am trying to make barbs on a feather. I think if I make a lot of edges separated at the same distance inside the feather, I might be able to make the barbs, but I am not sure how to do that. The reason I got rid of the inside gray part for the barb area is because it wasn't organized like I want the barbs to be.


Here is a photo of what I want to make: The feathers, rachis, barbs, barbules, and hooks. I'm not sure how to make the barbs, barbules, and hooks.

Image: Britannica, The Editors of Encyclopaedia. "feather". Encyclopedia Britannica, 21 Aug. 2024, https://www.britannica.com/science/feather. Accessed 14 October 2024.

I guess you could look for a hair tutorial

@DanielMöller I did try to use hairs at first, but I also wanted to added the barbules and hooks of the feather. I wasn't sure how to do that either.

Can you edit your post to show some reference of what you mean by "barbs"? I'm not sure I understand what you're aiming for.

@Jakemoyo I added an image of what I want to make.
